# how to implement a delete method from a trie?

Tags: java, trie

i have this trie code and i want to implement a delete method "delete(String s), can anyone help me with that?
i need it to take only the string as a parameter.

```java
class Trie {
    private TrieNode root;

    public Trie() {
        root = new TrieNode();
    }

    public void insert(String s) {
        TrieNode curNode = root;
        char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
        for (char curChar : arr) {
            if (curNode.children.containsKey(curChar) == false) {
                curNode.children.put(curChar, new TrieNode());
            }
            curNode = curNode.children.get(curChar);
        }
        curNode.isWord = true;
    }

    public boolean contains(String s)  {
        TrieNode curNode = root;
        char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
        for (char curChar : arr) {
            if (curNode.children.containsKey(curChar) == false) {
                return false;
            }
            curNode = curNode.children.get(curChar);
        }
        return curNode.isWord;
    }

    
    public boolean isPrefix(String p) {
        TrieNode curNode = root;
        char[] arr = p.toCharArray();
        for (char curChar : arr) {
            if (curNode.children.containsKey(curChar) == false) {
                return false;
            }
            curNode = curNode.children.get(curChar);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello ! Could you please edit your question and add the TrieNode class to your question. Also, what is the intended functionality of delete ? Do you want it to remove a child TrieNode and all of its children if the first character of the String is found (Top-Bottom) or do you want to delete TrieNodes from a Bottom up approach ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make `curNode.isWord` to `false` to indicate that it is deleted.

```
public boolean delete(String s)  {
    TrieNode curNode = root;
    char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
    for (char curChar : arr) {
        if (curNode.children.containsKey(curChar) == false) {
            return false;
        }
        curNode = curNode.children.get(curChar);
    }
    curNode.isWord = false;
    return true;
}
```